# asyncio.Queue as producer-consumer flow in a webserver like Quart

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, quart

Is it possible to use asyncio.Queue with a webserver like [Quart](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/) to communicate between the producer and consumer?

Here is what I am trying to do....

```
from quart import Quart, request
import asyncio

queue = asyncio.Queue()
producers = []
consumers = []


async def producer(mesg):
    print(f'produced {mesg}')
    await queue.put(mesg)
    await asyncio.sleep(1) # do some work


async def consumer():
    while True:
        token = await queue.get()
        await asyncio.sleep(1) # do some work
        queue.task_done()
        print(f'consumed {token}')


@app.route('/route', methods=['POST'])
async def index():
    mesg = await request.get_data()
    try:
        p = asyncio.create_task(producer(mesg))
        producers.append(p)
        c = asyncio.create_task(consumer())
        consumers.append(c)
        return f"published message {mesg}", 200
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception("Failed tp publish message %s!", mesg)
        return f"Failed to publish message: {mesg}", 400

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PORT = int(os.getenv('PORT')) if os.getenv('PORT') else 8050
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=PORT, debug=True)
```

This works fine. 
But I am not sure if this is a good practice because I am confused how (where in my code) to do the below steps.

```
# Making sure all the producers have completed
await asyncio.gather(*producers)

#wait for the remaining tasks to be processed
await queue.join()

# cancel the consumers, which are now idle
for c in consumers:
    c.cancel()
```

EDIT-1:

I have tried using `@app.after_serving`, with some `logger.debug` statements.

```
@app.after_serving
async def shutdown():
    logger.debug("Shutting down...")
    logger.debug("waiting for producers to finish...")
    await asyncio.gather(*producers)
    logger.debug("waiting for tasks to complete...")
    await queue.join()
    logger.debug("cancelling consumers...")
    for c in consumers:
        c.cancel()
```

But the debug statements are not printed when `hypercorn` is gracefully shutting down. So, I am not sure whether the function(shutdown) decorated with `@app.after_serving` is actually called during a shutdown.

Here is the message from `hypercorn` during shutdown

```
appserver_1  | 2020-05-29 15:55:14,200 - base_events.py:1490 -        create_server - INFO - <Server sockets=(<asyncio.TransportSocket fd=14, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 8080)>,)> is serving
appserver_1  | Running on 0.0.0.0:8080 over http (CTRL + C to quit)
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
```

I using a `kill -SIGTERM <PID>` to signal a graceful shutdown to the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would place the cleanup code in a shutdown [after_serving](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/how_to_guides/startup_shutdown.html) function,

```
@app.after_serving
async def shutdown():
    # Making sure all the producers have completed
    await asyncio.gather(*producers)

    #wait for the remaining tasks to be processed
    await queue.join()

    # cancel the consumers, which are now idle
    for c in consumers:
        c.cancel()
```

As for the globals, I tend to store them on the app directly so that they can be accessed via the `current_app` proxy. Please note though that this (and your solution) only works for a single process (worker), if you want to use multiple workers (or equivalently hosts) you will need a third party store for this information e.g. using redis.

Comment: I have tried using `@app.after_serving` not sure if it is called during shutdown, please look at `EDIT-1` in my post. thanks

Comment: Just checked that this works for me (it does). Could it be that your logger is not setup (e.g. log level) to emit the debug messages?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use a `time.sleep` inside `@app.after_serving`... So, at graceful shutdown hypercorn sleeps for N seconds before shutting down. Still doesn't log though.. i cant log the log statements inside `@app.after_serving`, but i can log the log statements in other functions...

Comment: Hypercorn, 0.10.0, has just gained a graceful timeout parameter which is likely to do the same as yours.
I can't explain why the logging would differ though - maybe try a print for sanity?

Answer (score 0):

> But I am not sure if this is a good practice

Global variables like the ones you've created in your example are not typically good practice in enterprise solutions. Especially in Python, there are some finicky behavior when it comes to globals.
Passing in variables to a function or class has been a cleaner approach from my experience.
However, I don't know how to do that in quart since I don't use that lib.

```
# Making sure all the producers have completed
#wait for the remaining tasks to be processed
# cancel the consumers, which are now idle
```

Typically clean up tasks are done upon exiting the event loop and before exiting the application.
I don't have knowledge of how `quart` works, but you might be able to put that logic after `app.run()` so that clean up tasks run after the event loop stops.
This might vary depending on how your application exits.
Check the documentation for some sort of a "on shutdown" event that you can hook into.